# Running multiple files with main function in a single Xcode project

Tags: c++, xcode, program-entry-point

By default, it creates a main.cpp file, which contains a Hello World message to print. When I try to add another C++ file to that project, which prints, say Foo, clicking the Run button still outputs Hello World only. How do I create multiple C++ files under that project and run them individually, without one referencing or depending upon the others?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be do have conditional blocks within all files, including a header file that contains some definitions. Simply comment out in the Definitions file what you don't want active

Definitions.h

```
#define __VARIABLE1__
// #define __VARIABLE2__
```

File 1:

```
#include "Definitions.h"
#ifdef __VARIABLE1__
  // code
#endif
```

File 2:

```
#include "Definitions.h"
#ifdef __VARIABLE2__
  // code
#endif
```